# How to change dates for salary assignment java

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jdbc, localdate

I have `employees` and `salaries` tables.

An employee can have more than one salary, and how that happens is he has a salary with the id that tells which employee it is, the salary amount, the `fromDate` (date when salary is assigned) and `toDate` (date when the salary has expired and a new salary has been assigned).

What I need is that when a new salary is assigned the `toDate` of the old salary is set to `LocalDate.now()` while the to date of the new salary is `null`.

```
public Employee save(Employee employee) {
    String sql = "Insert into employees(emp_no, birth_date,first_name, last_name, gender, hire_date) values (:empNo,:birthDate, :firstName, :lastName, cast(:gender as gender), :hireDate) " +
            "on conflict (emp_no) do update set birth_date = :birthDate, first_name= :firstName, last_name= :lastName, gender= cast(:gender as gender), hire_date= :hireDate";
    MapSqlParameterSource paramSource = new MapSqlParameterSource("empNo", employee.getEmpNo())
            .addValue("birthDate", employee.getBirthDate())
            .addValue("firstName", employee.getFirstName())
            .addValue("lastName", employee.getLastName())
            .addValue("gender", employee.getGender().toString())
            .addValue("hireDate", employee.getHireDate());
    namedParameterJdbcTemplate.update(sql, paramSource);
    if (!employee.getSalaries().isEmpty()) {
        for (Salary salary : employee.getSalaries()) {
            insertSalary(employee.getEmpNo(), salary);
            salary.setToDate(null);
        }
    }
    return employee;
}

private void insertSalary(Long empNo, Salary salary) {
    String sql = "insert into salaries (emp_no, salary, from_date, to_date) values (:empNo, :salary, :fromDate, :toDate) on conflict (emp_no, from_date) do update set to_date = :toDate";
    salary.setToDate(LocalDate.now());
    MapSqlParameterSource parameterSource = new MapSqlParameterSource("salary", salary.getSalary())
            .addValue("empNo", empNo)
            .addValue("fromDate", salary.getFromDate())
            .addValue("toDate", salary.getToDate());
    namedParameterJdbcTemplate.update(sql, parameterSource);
}


 @Override
    public Employee extractData(ResultSet rs) throws SQLException, DataAccessException {
        Map<Long, Employee> employeeById = new HashMap<>();
        Employee employee = new Employee();
        while (rs.next()) {

            Long empNo = rs.getLong("emp_no");
            if (employeeById.isEmpty()) {
                employee = employeeById.get(empNo);
            }
            Long salary = rs.getLong("salary");
            LocalDate fromDate = rs.getObject("from_date", LocalDate.class);
            LocalDate toDate= rs.getObject("to_date", LocalDate.class);
            Salary salary1 = new Salary(empNo, salary, fromDate, toDate);
            if (employee == null) {
                employee = new Employee();
                employeeById.put(employee.getEmpNo(), employee);
            }
            employee.assignSalary(salary1);
        }
        Collection<Employee> employees = employeeById.values();
        return employee;
    }
```

Comment: What exactly is the question? I'd say the easiest way would be to use 2 operations: 1) update the "old" salary which is identified by a `null` end date and 2) insert the new salary. You _could_ use 2 upserts which would amount to an update and an insert but you'd not gain much from this.

Comment: do you mean "call the insertSalary" method by "when a new salary is assigned"? If yes, you can add a method called "updateOldSalary" to perform what @Thomas wrote. Better to perform the operations in a single transaction

Comment: Btw, why does your `save()` call `salary.setToDate(null);` on _every_ salary?

Comment: The thing is i need to use that method to save and update, so i cant really do an update method, and i put that 'salary.setToDate(null)' to assign the toDate to the new salary to null but i removed it since it wasnt doing anything

Comment: i have done an upsert to the insertSalary method but im not sure if ive done it right